# What are some developed countries that have a laissez-faire approach to user data flowing abroad?

Tags: international, technology, privacy

> China has in recent years tightened controls on data and information,
> especially data and information that flows abroad.

https://www.reuters.com/world/china/china-make-holders-more-than-1-mln-users-data-get-annual-audits-2023-08-03/

What are some developed countries that has a laissez-faire approach to user data flowing abroad? I know that China is not developed, but this article made me wonder if there are countries that do not hold audits on company that holds user data and if some of them don't have any restriction on data being shared to any party abroad. By developing, I mean non-developing, countries with a high HDI.

Comment: Do you consider the USA to qualify? There was a lot of noise about banning applications like TikTok, but nothing happened, and audits of user data handling do not seem to be a thing there, outside of, say, Facebook's entirely voluntary civil rights audit, which it initiated itself. But a few states are moving toward data protection like the EU, particularly California, which appears geared to introduce audits soon. So does that count or not?

Comment: I mean, the U.S. is clearly a developed country, but I doubt they don't protect user data.

Comment: That depends what you mean. The fact that California is moving to adopting cybersecurity audits in connection with EU-like data protection standards suggests to me that the USA overall does not have anything of that sort. And the worries that some legislators have expressed about Chinese applications sharing data with the Chinese government exist precisely because there is not really a legal regime that would prevent it.